# How to capture video of iPhone game, in-game

Tags: iphone

I want the users of my game to be able to record video of the game while playing it similar to the app Talking Tom Cat. I was wondering how to accomplish this. Do you have any ideas? I want both video and audio of the game to be recorded...

Any clue would help :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to save your users input together with the frame index as a demofile if your game mechanics are deterministic. This way, you could let the game 'play itself' by reading the input form a file (which would be quite small compared to a full screen video with audio track) Thats the way DooM 1+2 and Quake 1 stored there Demos

Otherwise, i would look for 'screen scraping on iphone' on google.

Do they provide realtime video file generation on the IPhone? is it powerfull enough for this?

Another way would be to dump copies of your framebuffer to a file for each frame (or for 25 per second) and encode these to a video file afterwards. You will have to capture your sound to a file manually too, probaly strwaming it to flash while you are playing.

If these approaches are feasible on an iPhone, i don't know, but that's how I would try to implement such a thing on a PC.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to reply. It turns out that recording and playing back input is definitely the only way to go, however it isn't feasible for our game. Thanks for your answer!